# Sincronizacion python

Tags: python

Me podrían ayudar con este código, necesito hacer el `"faneuil Hall problem"` este dice lo siguiente:

> "There are three kinds of threads: immigrants, spectators, and a one
>   judge. Immigrants must wait in line, check in, and then sit down. At
>   some point, the judge enters the building. When the judge is in the
>   building, no one may enter, and the immigrants may not leave.
>   Spectators may leave. Once all immigrants check in, the judge can
>   confirm the naturalization. After the confirmation, the immigrants
>   pick up their certificates of U.S. Citizenship. The judge leaves at
>   some point after the confirmation. Spectators may now enter as before.
>   After immigrants get their certificates, they may leave."

La cosa es que al momento de sincronizar los hilos, el hilo del inmigrante no desbloquea al juez por lo que en el if me toma como `juez = 0`
No se que estoy haciendo mal si pudieran echarme una mano y explicarme en que me equivoque. Muchas gracias..

```
import threading
import time

condition = threading.Semaphore(1)
mutex = threading.Semaphore(1)
confirmar = threading.Event()


entrar = 0
registrar = 0
juez = 0

class Inmigrante(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        global entrar, registrar
        print ("comenzar inmigrante\n")

        condition.acquire()
        print("[%s]Inmigrante: Entrar\n" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        entrar += 1
        print("[%s]Inmigrante: Entrar: %d\n" % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), entrar))
        print ("aaa\n")
        condition.release()
        mutex.acquire()

        print("[%s]Inmigrante: Registar\n" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        registrar += 1
        print("[%s]Inmigrante: Registar: %d\n" % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), registrar))

        print ("valor de juez es: %d\n" % juez )
        if(juez == 1 and entrar == registrar):
            mutex.notify()

        else:
            mutex.release()

        print("[%s]Inmigrante: Sentarme\n" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        confirmar.wait()

        print("[%s]Inmigrante: Jurar\n" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        print("[%s]Inmigrante: Obtener certificado\n" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

        condition.acquire()
        print("[%s]Inmigrante: Salir\n" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        condition.release()

class Juez(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global entrar, registrar
        print ("comenzar juez\n")
        condition.acquire()
        mutex.acquire()

        print("[%s]Juez:Entrar\n" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        juez = 1
        print ("valor juezzzz: %d \n" % juez)
        print("[%s]Juez: Juez: %d\n" % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), juez))

        if(entrar > registrar):
            mutex.release()


        print("[%s]Juez:Confirmando a inmigrante\n" %   time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        confirmar.set()
        entrar = registrar = 0
        print("[%s]Juez: Entrar: %d Registrar: %d\n" % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), entrar, registrar))

        print("[%s]Juez:Salir\n" %   time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        juez = 0
        print("[%s]Juez: Juez: %d\n" % (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), juez))

        mutex.release()
        condition.release()

class Espectador(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print ("comenzar espectador\n")
        condition.acquire()

        print("[%s]Espectador: Entrar\n" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        condition.release()

        print("[%s]Espectador: Espectear\n" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

        print("[%s]Espectador: Salir\n" % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

inmigrante = Inmigrante()
judge = Juez()
espectador = Espectador()

inmigrante.start()
espectador.start()
judge.start()


inmigrante.join()
espectador.join()
judge.join()
```

Comment: Dentro de la clase `Juez` no defines tu variable `juez` como `global` por lo que solo la modificas localmente. Para el resto de hilos seguirá siendo 0.

Comment: Puse juez como global y me sigue pasando lo mismo, lo que pasa es que no me entra a esta linea, ya que juez es 0 if(juez == 1 and entrar == registrar):